Maximal subgroups of finite abelian $2$-groups
Suppose $G$ is a finite abelian $2$-group, and $S$ is a subset of $G$,  $\langle S\rangle=G$,$S^{-1}=S$,$e\notin S$. How to determine whether there exists a maximal subgroup $M$ of $G$, such that $S$ is contained in $G\setminus M$?

Write $G$ additively (and assume $G\neq{0}$, as the answer is no for $G={0}$). Let $N$ be the subgroup generated by $2G\cup{s-t:s,t\in S}$ (so $N$ has index at most 2). Then $M$ exists iff $N\cap S=\emptyset$ (in which case the only possible $M$ is $N$ itself).

@YCor why N has index at most 2?

Because modulo $N$, the set ${s-t:s,t\in S}$ is trivial, which means that modulo $N$, $S$ is a singleton. So $G/N$ is generated by a singleton, hence cyclic, since $2G\subset N$, we deduce that $G/N$ has order $1$ or $2$.

@YCor Sorry，I understand $2G$ is the Frattini subgroup of $G$, so $G/2G$ must be an elementary abelian $2$-group. However, I'm not quite sure about the role of the set ${s-t: s, t \in S}$. Why is the subgroup $N$ generated by  $2 G \cup{s-t: s, t \in S}$, either $G$ or a maximal subgroup?

What I'm saying is that the image of $S$ in $G/N$ is necessarily a singleton, because you killed all differences between elements of $S$.

Note that my first comment (with $N$ defined as the "normal subgroup generated by all squares and ${st^{-1}:s,t\in S}$") works assuming that $G$ is an arbitrary finite group. A restatement is that there exists $N$ with the given condition iff $S$ is contained in the nontrivial coset of some subgroup of index 2.

Here's an algorithm. Choose an element $s\in S$ and write down a list $A$ of the elements $st$ with $t\in S\setminus \{s\}$. Next, write down a basis $B$ for $\operatorname{\rm Hom}(G,\mathbb{Z}/2)$. This gives you a matrix whose columns are indexed by $A$ and rows by $B$, giving the values of the homomorphisms on the elements. Then the question amounts to whether the rows are linearly independent. So do a row reduction and see whether you get a zero row. Keeping track of the row reduction will give you a linear combination of your basis of homomorphisms, and the kernel is then your maximal subgroup $M$. This doesn't depend on $G$ being abelian.

but for any $G$ , how can i know the basis $B$ for $\operatorname{Hom}(G, \mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z})$.

Mod out squares and commutators, to get an elementary abelian $2$-group. Then it's a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_2$. How are you given your group?

(actually, every commutator in any group is a product of three squares, so you can just mod out squares)

Another way to look at it (given all the hypotheses), is that there is such a maximal subgroup $M$ if and only if there is an element $t \in S$ such that $St = \{st: s \in S \}$ does not generate $G$.
For if there is such an element $t$, take a maximal subgroup $M$ containing $\langle St \rangle.$ Then $t \not \in M$, for otherwise $t^{-1} \in M$ and $S = (St)t^{-1} \subseteq M,$ contrary to $G = \langle S \rangle.$ Hence $S = (St)t^{-1} \subseteq Mt^{-1}$ and $S \cap M = \emptyset$, since $t^{-1} \not \in M.$
On the other hand, if there is a maximal subgroup $M$ with $S \cap M = \emptyset,$ then for each $t \in S$, we have $S \subseteq Mt,$ since $G$ is the disjoint union $M \cup Mt.$ Then $St \subseteq Mt^{2} = M,$ so that $\langle St \rangle \neq G.$
As in @DaveBenson's answer, this only requires $G$ to be a finite $2$-group, not necessarily Abelian.
